# Escape HTML in markdown in HAML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xss, haml, markdown

Is it possible, in Rails 3.1, to escape HTML in markdown in HAML to avoid XSS? I mean when you do something like:

```
:markdown
  Hello #{@user.name}
```

Thanks.

Comment: which rails version are you using? with rails 3, it should by XSS safe. to insert html from a database column you would need to do @user.name.html_safe

Comment: @MarianTheisen, I'm running Rails 3.1.

Comment: @J.PabloFernández It is possible to implement your own custom filter in which you escape html before passing it to the markdown filter...

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek: I'll have to do that apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I created this:

```
module Haml::Filters::SafeMarkdown
  include Haml::Filters::Base
  lazy_require "rdiscount", "peg_markdown", "maruku", "bluecloth"

  def render(text)
    engine = case @required
               when "rdiscount"
                 ::RDiscount
               when "peg_markdown"
                 ::PEGMarkdown
               when "maruku"
                 ::Maruku
               when "bluecloth"
                 ::BlueCloth
             end
    engine.new(Haml::Helpers.html_escape(text)).to_html
  end
end
```

and to make it easy to use it directly:

```
module SafeMarkdown
  def self.render(text)
    Haml::Filters.defined["safemarkdown"].render(text).html_safe
  end
end
```

It seems to work for now. Does anybody have a comment?

Comment: Won't using this mean any inline html you want to add to your markdown will also be escaped? I've been playing around a bit and come up with this: https://gist.github.com/c1d81126463c128d5515 if you want. It's a hack more than anything so I don't think it's worth its own answer. If you do base something on this, note the warning: "Warning: the Haml::Compiler interface is neither well-documented nor guaranteed to be stable. If you want to make use of it, you’ll probably need to look at the source code and should test your filter when upgrading to new Haml versions."

Comment: @matt: true, but I generally don't want html in markdown, and when I do, I handle the safety of those strings manually. I'm not sure if this solution works in the long run.